# How do I find dy/dx by implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Find $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$ by implicit differentiation.

$\tan(x+y)=x$

So far, I got to

$\displaystyle \sec^2(x+y) \left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = 1$

but then im lost.. can someone please help and explain? I would really appreciate it!!

Comment: Can you rearrange `dy/dx` to isolate it on one side?

Comment: Solve for $dy/dx$, by moving everything else to the right hand side.

Comment: What Thomas wrote!  And tabstop!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have $\sec^2(x+y) (1+ y') = 1$, from which you get $y' = \cos^2(x+y)-1$.

Comment: @ copper.hat:  I didn't know you were capable of such advanced work! ;-)!!! +1.  Yours from where else--Caffe Mediterraneum, Beserkeley, CA!

Comment: @RobertLewis: I have my moments :-). Enjoy the Med! I need some Med therapy!

Comment: @ copper.hat:  so come on down!

Answer (score 0):

you need to foil sec$^2(x+y)(1+ y'(x)) =1$ and then solve for $y'(x)$.

Think about sec$^2(x+y)$ as one whole.

Hint: the answer will be in terms of $x$ and $y$